# Bounded dependence on initial conditions of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x’ = f(t,x)$ , $x(t_0) = a$, $y’=f(t,y)$, $y(t_0) = b$

We want to bound how far will the solutions be in some time $t > t_0$.

I seem to recall that if $f$ is L-Lipstipchz then the following bound holds:

$|x(t) - y(t)| ≤ e^{L(t-t_0)}|x(t_0)-y(t_0)|$

Is this true? What other conditions are needed? What are other nice bounds?

Comment: Are there any reference for this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your bound is right. It is optimal in some sense because if you have, say, $f(x,t)=x$ and consider the solutions with some $a>0$ and $b=0$, their difference is exactly $ae^{t}$, which is your bound with $L=1$.